# splitting the string based on multiple spaces

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a string like below

```
ABC PQR 123  R1234 TREW
```

I need to split it and put individual values in the database.

The database table looks like this

```
Col1   Col2    Col3  Col4  Col5       Col6

 ABC   PQR     123         R1234      TREW
```

I can use the split function to split at spaces, but sometimes there are more than one space and then I want to insert a blank in the table so in the above string, I have two spaces between 123 and R1234. I need to insert space in Col4 to represent that there is nothing in that part of the string. There can be more than two spaces so that will mean Col4 and Col5 both can be empty so whenever there are two spaces, I need to enter space in that corresponding column and if there is one space then I need to enter the value in the database. How can I achieve that.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about `"ABC PQR 123   R1234  TREW  ".Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` ? : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Because that won't give him an empty entry for `Col4`

Comment: @tnw Ah! You're absolutely right! Didn't notice that empty column.

Comment: @tnw Looks like this string is read from a column-based text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this can be parse using [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Have a [look at this nice article](http://www.emoreau.com/Entries/Articles/2010/05/Do-you-know-the-TextFieldParser.aspx) that allows to specify the the fields length as well.

A part from the link:

```
reader.SetFieldWidths(5, 21, 7, -1)
```

Using this you can handle the variable length fields as well.

Comment: While i can also recommend the class and using an available parser is better than reinventing the wheel, `SetFieldWidths` does not help here since the fields don't have a fixed length.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, but i guess after reading first line we can get the field lengths

Answer (score 1):

So you have columns which are separated by space, not a problem as long as the value itself does not contain a space. You just have to use  `String.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.None)`:

```
 string[] allFields = str.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Now every string in the `string[]` is a column value for your table. If there is an empty string that means the column's value is also empty.

So presuming sql-server:

```
string[] allFields = "ABC PQR 123  R1234 TREW".Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if(allFields.Length >= 6)   // == 6 if more values than columns is exceptional
{
    string sql = @"INSERT INTO table(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6)
                   VALUES(@Col1,@Col2,@Col3,@Col4,@Col5,@Col6)";
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", allFields[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", allFields[1]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col3", allFields[2]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col4", allFields[3]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col5", allFields[4]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col6", allFields[5]);
        con.Open();
        int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to let him figure that out- but here are the links I was going to supply for reference...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/trim

Comment: I'm also not sure if OP realizes that his string has *three* spaces between `123` and `R1234`, resulting in an additional blank entry in the array I'm guessing he doesn't want. Additionally, there's three more after `TREW`. This won't *quite* get him what he wants.

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle, it demonstrates what I'm talking about.  This works for columns 1-4 using his exact string, but this solution falls apart afterwards. https://dotnetfiddle.net/eYXkAK

Comment: @Rufus because it was clearly stated that empty spaces mean an empty value for that column.

Comment: @tnw: i see that OP's sample is falling apart. The solution works as expected ;) If the input contains more values than columns all superfluous will be ignored.

Comment: @TimSchmelter If the expectation is putting incorrect values in the database, sure :) but I see your point, doesn't seem OP understands that the whitespace in his string is different than what he is describing. Removed downvote, but won't upvote either as this doesn't really give him the values in his DB that he describes

Comment: value can contain a space.

Comment: @tnw: if more values than columns is exceptional OP should replace `if(allFields.Length >= 6)` with `if(allFields.Length == 6)`.

Comment: @user3862503: then you have a problem. How do you want to differentiate between separators and values?

Comment: Yeah what is actually going on here? There's single, double, and triple spaces in the string. Not sure how that's to be interpreted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Could it be that this is a string read from a column-based text file (or whatever) where each column has a fixed length?

Comment: No, each column does not have a fixed length. The reason there arte spaces because some of the data is empty and user wants me to insert empty string/space in the database.

Comment: @user3862503: then _"value can contain a space"_ was just confusing. You mean that not the column-value can contain spaces but only between the columns which is not a problem. But what about more than two spaces like in your sample string? Do you want to skip all spaces after the second and continue with the next non-space or do you want to fill three columns (or even more) with empty spaces?

Comment: @user3862503: i have fixed your invalid sample data that does not correspond to what you've mentioned(f.e. _"two spaces between 123 and R1234"_, there were 3).